# Image file compression options with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, compression

Is it possible to compress the file size of a figure using `ggsave`?  I have tried using the `compression = "lzw"` argument, but the file size remains the same. (Using R studio .98.501 OS-X Yosemite)

My code:

```
ggsave("Figure1.tiff", width = 14, height = 8, dpi=600, compression = "lzw")
```

Is it possible to add a compression argument with ggsave?

Answer (score 11):

**UPDATE:**

I just tried this option with **ggplot2 2.2.1**. If you save using the file ending `".tiff"`, and specify `compression = "lzw"`, (*exactly as written by @Derelict*), ggsave will now compress your image appropriately. Mine went from 2.98 MB to 37.6 KB.

Answer (score 2):

If you can, try saving the image as a PDF. They're really clean vector graphics (if you want to refine in something like Illustrator) and I typically see them in the 3-5 KB range.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use tiff directly, like

```
tiff("my_graph.tif", units="in", width=13.3, height=6.6, res=800, compression = "lzw")

my_graph <- ggplot(....)

dev.off()
```