# reduce size of plots in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I want to reduce size of GGplot I created. The size exceeds 50mbs I think there is a problem with size, Kindly help

```
data=read.csv("C:/Users/Muhammad Faisal/Desktop/WP07/FORMC.csv",header=T)
tiff('FORMCOBSPRED.JPEG', units="in", width=4, height=3, res=1200)
ggplot(data=data, aes(y=Enalapril, x=Predicted))+theme_bw()+ geom_abline( size=1,col="black",linetype=(1))+
  geom_point(data=data, colour="black", size=1)+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text( size=12),
        axis.text.x  = element_text( vjust=0.5, size=12,colour = "black"))+
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text( size=12),
        axis.text.y  = element_text( vjust=0.5, size=12,colour = "black"))+
  scale_shape(solid =F)+geom_smooth(method="lm",se=F, size=1, colour="red",linetype=(2))+
  ylab("Observed enalapril (ug/L)")+xlab("Predicted enalapril (ug/L)")+ scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,120,30))+ scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,120,30))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5 ))
dev.off()
```

Comment: Hi Faisal, can you produce a reproducible example, say by sharing a git repository. This will help us in replicating your results.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add a reproducible example, putting your data `dput()` or some fake data similar to your.

Comment: this is a scatter plot. I dont know how to put the data here, I shall appreciate if anyone can guide me. Shall I just make dataframe and put it here?

Comment: @MuhammadFaisal to make a reproducible example you could use a R dataset e.g. ggplot2::diamonds; and adjust your codes accordingly

Comment: you should probably try to lower the resolution, `1200` is a high one and probably the reason why the size of your file is that big

Comment: Changing `tiff()` to `jpeg()` might help. You can avoid this if you use `ggsave()`. I'll post an example...

Comment: Related, possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29419461/file-compression-options-with-ggplot2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tiff` doesn't care how you name your file, it will save as tiff, which results in the big size. Therefore, you should change `tiff('FORMCOBSPRED.JPEG', units="in", width=4, height=3, res=1200)` to `jpeg('FORMCOBSPRED.JPEG', units="in", width=4, height=3, res=1200)`. If you use `ggsave`, it will save it according to your file extension, thus as jpeg. See comparison below:

```
library(ggplot2)
# tiff will result in huge size, even though you name it .jpeg:
tiff("iris_tiff.jpeg", units="in", width=4, height=3, res=1200)
qplot(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length, color = Species, data = iris, geom = "point")
dev.off()
file.size("iris_tiff.jpeg") # size is 51840192

# using jpeg() solves that Problem:
jpeg("iris_jpeg.jpeg", units="in", width=4, height=3, res=1200)
qplot(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length, color = Species, data = iris, geom = "point")
dev.off()

file.size("iris_jpeg.jpeg") # size is 563329

# if we use the functionality of ggsave, which automatically determines type given extension:
ggsave(filename = "iris.jpeg", 
       plot = qplot(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length, color = Species, data = iris, geom = "point"),
       units="in", width=4, height=3, dpi=1200)

file.size("iris.jpeg") # size is 563329, hence same as jpeg()

# same for tiff-extension:
ggsave(filename = "iris.tiff", 
       plot = qplot(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length, color = Species, data = iris, geom = "point"),
       units="in", width=4, height=3, dpi=1200)

file.size("iris.tiff") # size is 51840192, hence same as tiff()
```

Comment: Tino that is wonderful, Thank you very much it has solved the problem by not using tiff. i am very thankful to you. Cheers

Comment: Thank you everyone for the time.

Comment: Glad it solved your problem. You might want to accept the answer then. Cheers!