# geom_point with many data points, the file size of the plot is too big.

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a scatter plot with many data points in it. Once I try to zoom in or save it in a pdf format, it takes a long time to open and the pdf is too large. How can I reduce the file size or make the plot lighter by keeping the same visuality of the plot. Here is an example:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(50000),y=rnorm(50000))
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File compression options with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29419461/file-compression-options-with-ggplot2)

Comment: Do you need it in .pdf format, or is compression an option? If so, this answer might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you mean with visibility. But what about the following?

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(50000),y=rnorm(50000))
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point()
ggsave('C:/yourpath/test.png', dpi = 600)
```

This should result in a .png file of roughly 85 kb.

If you want to increase the quality of the picture, you can increase `dpi` into `1200` or higher.